# Como criar menus personalizados em wordpress que respeitam a ordem do drag and drop

Tags: css, html5, wordpress, bootstrap, menu

Estou com problemas para criar menus no meu site wordpress no caso tenho mais de um menu que precisam respeitar a ordem de criação, mas nunca respita, o menu está ordenado por ordem alfabetica, alguém tem idéia de como eu faço isso?

Comment: Vc tem o link do site, ou algum lugar onde possamos simular o erro? Provavelmente nas opções do Tema na área do administrador do site deve ter uma opção de "sort" para definir a ordem se é alfabética, mais novo primeiro, mais antigo primeiro, etc...

Comment: @hugocsl eu acho que não ficou muito claro rs, esse tema foi eu mesmo que criei não estou utilizando nenhum tema de terceiro, eu até consigo definir o menu que quero usar o unico problema são os itens do menu que não ficam na ordem definida do drag drop correta!

Comment: Cara posta o que vc tem de código, e imagens de como está e como vc gostaria, tente colocar mais detalhes, pois do jeito que está fica difícil te ajudar...